# wp7 override current language

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-8

I want the user to choose his language in my app so if he chooses a different Language (because he wants to test his skills in other languages) than the Phone default language, I want all my globalized Strings to be changed during runtime. 
Is there the possibility to override the culture Info in c# for wp7 or wp8 for the runtime of current app?

Answer (score 1):

In `App.xaml.cs`, in the `InitializePhoneApplication` method:

```
private void InitializePhoneApplication()
{
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("fr-FR");
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
    .......
}
```

Be sure to edit you .csproj project file to set support for the languages you want to use in the `SupportedCultures` tag:

```
<SupportedCultures>en;fr-FR</SupportedCultures>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the quick response. But is it possible to change this during runtime. I think the App.xaml.cs is only loaded once durng the init of the App.